# Wrong content in popup window after "Like it"

Tags: popup, window, facebook-like

I added the like facebook button on my website, it works well except that the popup window doesn't show me the correct content.

Simple sample:
In the homepage of my website I set the title tag to its name, suppose it is called "the universe".
Then I go to another page that has a title like "the sun is hot". If I click "like it" on this page the popup content shows me "the universe". This is wrong, I want "the sun is hot".

How to set the correct content on the popup window? Does the button "like it" take the title tag or what else?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does the like button refer to the url of the homepage and not the page you are actually on? The way the like buttons work now is they pull the meta Open Graph tags from the url in the like button, so the meta tags on the page called by the button dictates the content.
If you make it the url the current page with the correct meta, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Run the page your like button is pointing at through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
This will show you the metadata Facebook is detecting for that URL, and/or clear the cache if you've updated the meta tags on your site recently